# scope of activities of a variable?

Tags: twig

I have the following code :

```
  {% set foo="abcdef" %}
```

I want foo function can operate in matches :

```
 {{ "abcdef" matches '/foo/i' ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

I want the result to be: yes

please help me.thanks you

Comment: Convert `'/foo/i'` to separated parts and concatenate the string using **~** which will be something like `'/' ~ foo ~ '/i'`

Answer (score 1):

Just do the string concatenation with `~`:

```
{{ "abcdef" matches '/' ~ foo ~ '/i' ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```